# Add Triggered Segues in Custom Controller as SplitViewContoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, interface-builder

Tell me please!
As I can add Triggered Segues for my custom controller class as SplitViewController? that would be visible in the Interface Builder.

[[image: example in SplitViewController[1]]

I tried like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

IB_DESIGNABLE

@interface SegueViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic) IBInspectable UIStoryboardSegue *master1;
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIStoryboardSegue *master2;
//@property (nonatomic) IBAction UIStoryboardSegue *master3; // error

@end
```

but it did not succeed

[image]